# Map markers in react-leaflet not showing image correctly

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm confused about creating map markers in react-leaflet; some of the documentation seems to be out of date and I've seen conflicting answers on other sites.

The default `<Marker>` component from the official documentation's setup, with no `icon` property described, displays as what looks like a rectangular indent in the map. Essentially it has a shadow but no actual marker icon. If `icon` is set to a `const` importing a certain image file, the marker displays as a squashed version of that image. I experimented with setting `icon` to `'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png'` but it looks really odd as the edges are fuzzy and the icon itself looks distorted (compressed horizontally - obviously 25x55 are the dimensions I copied from elsewhere but they don't look right as default).

What's the correct way to render a normal, default, standard map marker in react-leaflet?

My code (with the squashed icon from leaflet/dist) is here:

```
import './App.css';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import L, { divIcon } from 'leaflet';
import bear1 from './bulgaria-bear-1.jpg';
import bear2 from './bulgaria-bear-2.jpg';
import bear3 from './bulgaria-bear-3.jpg';
import markerIcon from 'leaflet/dist/images/marker-icon.png';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';

[...]

function PageMap(props) {
  const markerIconConst = L.icon({
    iconUrl: markerIcon,
    iconRetinaUrl: markerIcon,
    iconAnchor: [5, 55],
    popupAnchor: [10, -44],
    iconSize: [25, 55],
  });
  return (
    <div classname="App">
      <MapContainer id="mapid" center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false}>
        <TileLayer
          attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
          url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
        />
        <Marker icon={markerIconConst} position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
          <Popup>
            A pretty CSS3 popup. <br /> Easily customizable.
          </Popup>
        </Marker>
      </MapContainer>
      <p classname="App-header">
        <button onClick={(() => props.navigate('Home'))}>
          Home
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  );
```

As an additional question, I'm wondering why my other CSS doesn't get loaded on the map page, for example the button set as "App-header" which is meant to align with the centre. The button displays but is aligned at left. Does the MapContainer take over the whole page for its own CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct.
The dimensions for the Leaflet marker are 24x41.
For the button style, add an uppercase "N" to className (instead of `classname = "App-header"`).

You can find a demo here : [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gplvzs?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: This worked for me well. My issue was: Locally the location pin was visible but upon deployment, it would not show. Am now good. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I have used in my step by step tutorial to create custom image markers using react and leaflet.

```
import L from 'leaflet';

export const VenueLocationIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: require('../assets/venue_location_icon.svg'), 
  iconRetinaUrl: require('../assets/venue_location_icon.svg'),  
  iconAnchor: null,
  shadowUrl: null,
  shadowSize: null,  
  shadowAnchor: null,
  iconSize: [35, 35],
  className: 'leaflet-venue-icon'
});
```