# Leaflet Double Marker Issue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, express, leaflet

I'm using Leaflet with VueJs. When adding marker at particular location I'm getting a double marker at said location :

[image]

The code for the same looks like this :

```
    mounted() {
      this.map = L.map("mapContainer").setView([51.1657, 10.4515], 6.4);
      L.tileLayer("http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
        attribution:
          '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors',
      }).addTo(this.map);
      //use a mix of renderers
      var customPane = this.map.createPane("customPane");
      var canvasRenderer = L.canvas({ pane: "customPane" });
     
      customPane.style.zIndex = 399; // put just behind the standard overlay pane which is at 400
      L.marker([51.715019, 8.751960]).addTo(this.map).bindPopup('Machine 102')
    .openPopup();
      L.marker([48.1351, 11.5820]).addTo(this.map).bindPopup('Machine 101')
    .openPopup();
    },
```

I hope to get single marker as the output

Comment: That's the place for the shadow of the marker. Read https://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69051667/map-markers-in-react-leaflet-not-showing-image-correctly

Comment: is there a way to remove the shadow ?

Answer (score 0):

According to the leaflet documentation  [on markers](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#marker), the markers use the urls of images set in the icon variable for the marker and its shadow.

It seems that somehow the url for the shadow image is the same as the one from your marker. The only way I managed to get the same image was by explicitly setting it:

```
// define the icon
var myIcon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-icon.png',  //url of your marker. I think this one is the one you have
    shadowUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-icon.png',
    iconSize: [38, 30],
    iconAnchor: [22, 94],  // location of icon
    popupAnchor: [-3, -76],  //location of your pop-up
    shadowSize: [50, 20],
    shadowAnchor: [20, 90]  // location of shadow
});
// create the marker using the 'MyIcon' defined above:
 L.marker([51.715019, 8.751960],{icon: myIcon}).addTo(this.map).bindPopup('Machine 102').openPopup();
```

[double shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhfEB.png)

If you remove the shadow properties, then it shouldn't appear:

```
var myIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/images/marker-icon.png',
            iconSize: [38, 38],
            iconAnchor: [22, 94],
            popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
});
```

You can also try to set the `shadowUrl` to false, to make sure it overrides any inherited shadow location you might have:

```
shadowUrl:false
```